# Can´t see Counchdb via Android´s webview

Tags: android, jquery, webview, couchdb, couchbase

Is it possible to get a Android WebView to open a port like: 5984?
I need to get [some jquery](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1052006/) from the 'assets-folder' to $.get() my [counchdb](https://github.com/couchbase/Android-EmptyApp) json-data via the webview.

**But first** I just make a little test to see if android´s webview could get a response from counchdb:

```
webview.loadUrl("http://127.0.0.1:5984");
```

If I use the android´s build-in browser then I get:

```
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.2.0a-7b47329-git"}
```

But **NOT** via Android´s WebView, I just get a blank screen([see code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1052009/)) :(

**A little update:**
I look like if I switch for Vertical to horizontal, then
I get the data from couchdb([see log](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1054079/)).

*So maybe couchdb need to be in it own thread..*

Comment: If you're trying to get something from the assets folder, just use the `AssetsManager` class. Other than that, I can't help you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Nop.. I am trying to get jquery´s $.get function to retrieve json-data from the counchdb(is on my devise) NB: the jquery is in a html-file in the assets folder. Is like the Android Webview can´t open port 5984...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it look like couchdb must have some time to startup... so if you just put all your couchdb request inside, func like jquerys onclick(), or keyup()... then all is god.